# Replacing Commander breakers with something still available

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I've got an old Commander panel. I'd like to replace a breaker (old oven was 40 amps, new one specifies a 20 amps breaker). There's some sort of metal caps over the breakers. I found BQL220, online, which state:

> Eaton bolt-on replacement breaker for Commander and Cutler-Hammer QL/QM panels..*

But those new breakers don't have the same cap, so I'm wondering if they are an actual fit.

Candidate: https://www.canadabreakers.ca/products/bql220

Edit: https://www.canadabreakers.ca/products/qbh220 (after noticing the panel model starts with BC-)

Current panel:

[image]

Is this a fit? Any gotchas in installing those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eaton makes breakers for this panel.  They are the BQL, BQLT and BQGF.

https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electrical-circuit-protection/circuit-breakers/residential-circuit-breakers/eaton-brand-circuit-breakers-vintage-loadcentres-sales-aids-sa3103sk-ca.pdf

It looks like that website you linked is doing "SEO" to target Google search terms such as "commander breaker replacement", and what they bring to the table is "being easy to find".  What they take is "an outlandish markup" on common Eaton breakers you can get from any Eaton dealer.  I see a review where an electrician claims these prices are better than regular suppliers, but fake reviews are common on sites like this.

I would contact your local Eaton authorized dealer (i.e. local **electrical supply houses**, call the first one and ask if they know which ones are Eaton dealers) and see what they can get you that breaker for.  May not be that much.

Comment: ok, this is super useful. Looking at the page https://www.eaton.com/ca/en-gb/catalog/electrical-circuit-protection/replacement-bolt-on-breakers.technical.html and noticing the "Cat no. BC" label on the panel, doesn't that mean they are QBH ?

Answer (score 0):

Those metal caps are probably what are called handle ties.

They make sure when two single breakers(for 240 volts or a MWBC) are used on a circuit they both turn off together.

Your old stove is probably 240 volts, how many volts is the new one?

If 240 also will need two single 20 amps with a handle tie or a dual 20 amp breaker.  Handle ties are usually sold separately for single breakers.

Comment: It assures they both *are manually shut off* together. It does not provide "common trip", that comes from an internal mechanism.  Common trip is needed for 240V appliances with neutral, or MWBCs that serve 240V loads.

Answer (score -1):

Many of the big box stores In the US carry replacement breakers, I assume they do so in Canada. They generally also post a cross reference showing what to use as a replacement. I believe they were made by EATON and are no longer approved. If it is reasonable I would suggest replacing the panel as they are no longer approved for new construction. The replacement breakers I found are very expensive. As for the "Eaton bolt-on replacement breaker for Commander and Cutler-Hammer QL/QM panels." It would be worth a try as they made the original breaker. Without seeing the inside of the panel this is the best I can do with the information given.

Comment: These are bolt-on breakers. A bit harder to find.

Comment: And, as I understand it, possibly a bit more hazardous to change, since they involve bolts into electrically live bus bars? Worth a reminder if I'm recalling that correctly. Not quite the walk in the park that snap-in breakers are.

Comment: Wait, if I turn the whole panel off, the bus bar stops being live, right? I don't have enough experience with panels to open one without turning it OFF